# How to run another piece of code on Form2 if a button is pressed on Form1?

Tags: c#

Hard to provide code to show what is trying to be done, but here is the run down:

I have a button on Form1 that says "Lock On", and I have a statement in Form2 that reads data from Form1 before "lock on" is pressed (as in when all forms are loaded). I want Form1 to read data IF "lock on" is pressed, not before it is.

Is there a way to do it?

This is what I want to run if it is pressed:

```
private void FOne_Reader_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Reads fruit information

        //if lock on is pressed, do this:
        FOne_Reader.Enabled = true;
        Fruit fruity = new Fruit();
        string FileToRead = "../../../DLL/XML/Fruit_Event.xml";
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fruit));
        fruity = (Fruit)XMLHandler.READXML(FileToRead, serializer);

        //if not
      ...
```

Comment: What is stopping you now? You have references from one form to the other right? Once you clarify (in your head and on the posting) what are the steps you want, you can chain calls to follow your logic.

Comment: your question is confusing.  First you say that `Form2 that reads data from Form1 before "lock on" is pressed.`  and then you say `I want Form1 to read data IF "lock on" is pressed, not before it is.`  Are both forms reading data?  do you not want Form2 to read from Form1 before the button is pressed?  The code you have looks like it's reading data from disk, as opposed to another form.

Comment: I'm assuming I can do it through a if statement. But I'm not quite sure how to check if a button is pressed in another form. The reader that is there currently is enabled on the form load and checks every 2 seconds. I want it to check when "Lock On" is pressed instead

Comment: You need to subscribe to the `Clicked` event on the button.

Comment: and what do you mean by pressed?  does clicking the botton toggle it on or off? or does it mean that you've clicked on the button and are still holding down the mmmouse

Comment: @SamIam If you click the button, it enables it. Yes, toggle--but I'll likely have another button to turn it off instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using events:

Form1 code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event Action PressLock;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        Form2 dlg=new Form2();
        dlg.OtherFrom=this;            
        dlg.Show();
    }

    private void lockOnButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.PressLock!=null)
        {
            this.PressLock();
        }
    }
}
```

Form2 code:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Form1 form;
    public Form1 OtherFrom
    {
        get { return form; }
        set
        {
            this.form=value;
            this.form.PressLock += new Action(ReadFromForm1);
        }
    }

    public void ReadFromForm1()
    {
        // xml reading here
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what is going on in the Form2 code, but the `OnLoad` section I'm not quite getting. I'm guessing when the form loads, it does something...so what is `dlg`?

Comment: That's where you create your new Form2. The next line after that is the important part where you pass a reference to Form1(this). He put that code in OnLoad but you might have it somewhere else, it doens't matter.

Comment: @WisdomIns - Can you please post the code on how `Form1` and `Form2` are created and where there are shown. There is 1 GUI thread and both must run on the same thread, so that's why I created `Form2` when `Form1` loads.